# Removing an outer array:

Tags: php, arrays

IF you have an array within an array, how can you remove the outer array:

```
$outer_array = array(0 => array(
                                'key1' => 'value1',
                                'key2' => 'value2'
     ));
```

print_r($outer_array) produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
        )

)
```

Is there a function built into php so you are left with:

```
        Array
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
        )
```

Comment: `$sub_array = $outer_array[0]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
$new_array = $outer_array[0];
print_r($new_array);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => value1
    [key2] => value2
)
```

**Note:** As pointed out by @netcoder, to make it work for both numeric and string indexes, you can do:

```
$new_array = $outer_array[0];
$new_array = reset($out_arr);
```

Comment: Note: You can use [reset](http://php.net/reset), to ensure it works with both numeric and string indexes, like this: `$in_arr = reset($out_arr);`

Answer (score 6):

You can simple do  :

```
print_r(array_shift($outer_array))
```

Hope this will work