# Remove parent array from multidimensional array in php

Tags: php

using php how to get array result into below way,

```
 Array
    (
        [3] => Array
            (
                [15] => 15
                [16] => 16
                [17] => 17
                [18] => 18
                [19] => 19
            )

    )
```

how to convert above array into below format,

```
 Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 16
            [2] => 17
            [3] => 18
            [4] => 19
        )
```

Comment: Append all child elements into a separate array and then go from there. I'm thinking `foreach` would work. Not sure if that's the most convenient, but it will work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing an outer array:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009759/removing-an-outer-array)

Comment: If you dont know index of outter array and use php > 5.6 `array_merge(...$array)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) is your friend;

Presuming your array exists in a variable called `$array`;

```
$newArray = array_values($array[3]);
```

Answer (score 3):

you should use **RecursiveArrayIterator** to remove parent array

```
$arr = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($multidimensional_array));
$new_arr = iterator_to_array($arr, false);
```

Comment: Works great, even in PHP 5.3.  However, for some reason I can't get it to work as a function.  Any idea on that?  Seems simple enough, yet doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

try this, if you have more than one sub-array, it will work.

```
$arr = array(3 =>
        array
          ( 
           15  => 15,
           16 => 16,    
           17    => 17,  
           18    => 18,  
           19    => 19
          )
        );
    $new = array();
        foreach ($arr as $v){
            $new = array_merge($new , array_values($v)) ;
        }
echo "<pre>"; print_r($new);
```

[Working Demo](https://3v4l.org/KlE0t)

Answer (score 1):

Have not tested it but should work as per your requirement.

```
<?php
$parent array = array(); // The array which you want to change
$result_array = array(); // The array that will hold the results
foreach( $parent_array as $child_array )
{
    if( is_array( $child_array ) )
    {
        foreach( $child_array as $element )
        {
            $result_array[] = $element
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result_array);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty simple, as you can just assign the array holding variable to the values of one index …

```
<?php

/* build list */
for($i=15;$i<=19;$i++)
    $b[$i] = $i;
$a[3] = $b;

var_export($a);

/* make array smaller again */
$a = $a[3];

var_export($a);

/* reindexing, just values */
$a = array_values( $a );

var_export($a);

?>
```

the reindexing part is done by a build-in function, also have a look on php.net for the linked functions for arrays, you can do massive stuff simple with them.