# How to convert multi-dimensional array into one-dimensional array

Tags: php

I have below array with multi dimensional array. How I can convert it into one dimensional array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21134
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21135
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21137
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21138
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21144
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21147
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21149
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21150
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21151
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21152
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21153
        )

)
```

Comment: What's you expected output?

Comment: Go through this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009759/removing-an-outer-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009759/removing-an-outer-array)

Comment: this might help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754980/how-to-convert-two-dimensional-array-to-one-dimensional-array-in-php5]

Comment: My expected output should be like Array (
[0] => 21134
[1] => 21135
[2] => 21137
[3] => 21138
[4] => 21144
[5] => 21147
[6] => 21149
)

Answer (score 4):

This case `array_column()` is very useful:

```
$resultArray = array_column($yourArray,'id');
```

If will give you the values of all the id's in a one-dimensional array.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Answer (score 1):

use `array_column()`

**eg:**

```
$array = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21134
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21135
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21137
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21138
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21144
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21147
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21149
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21150
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21151
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21152
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21153
        )

)
```

use `array_column()` to convert it, like this,

```
$result = array_column($array,'id');
```

Comment: how does this differ from KIKO's answer?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs: sorry i did't see that answers

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)** for multidimensional array into one-dimensional array

```
$oneDimensionalArray = array_map('current', $twoDimensionalArray);
```

you can also **[array_merge](http://php.net/array_merge)**

```
$oneDimensionalArray = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $twoDimensionalArray);
```