# PHP multidimensional array: remove outer array, remove index keys & remaining arrays separate by comma

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array.

- I want to remove its outer array & index keys.
- then return remaining arrays separate by comma

following code gives similar result what I want but it returns only one array by using its index [0]. this code is from [Removing an outer array:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009759/removing-an-outer-array)

```
$new_array = $outer_array[0];
$new_array = reset($out_arr);
```

This is my multidimensional array

```
$old_array = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [taxonomy] => updatable-category
            [field] => term_id
            [terms] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 136
                    [1] => 134
                    [2] => 135
                )

            [operator] => IN
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [taxonomy] => apps-category
            [field] => term_id
            [terms] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 126
                    [1] => 124
                    [2] => 125
                )

            [operator] => IN
        )

);
```

following is required result. Note: the returning arrays here must be separated by comma

```
$new_array = Array
(
    [taxonomy] => updatable-category
    [field] => term_id
    [terms] => Array
        (
            [0] => 136
            [1] => 134
            [2] => 135
        )

    [operator] => IN
)
,
Array
(
    [taxonomy] => apps-category
    [field] => term_id
    [terms] => Array
        (
            [0] => 126
            [1] => 124
            [2] => 125
        )

    [operator] => IN
);
```

Comment: the requested result should be set where? in string variable or in array too? Or you like just a print this arrays with comma separator? Explain what you trying to do with desired result.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco the result will be passed to an array variable. question updated.

Comment: Your desired result is not a valid value for PHP. Are you trying to iterate through the outer array? Or do you just want to display the values? Or???